# Get data from database for graph Android

Tags: android, sqlite, graph, cursor

I have setup a SQLite database in my android application. I used a tutorial from google and my database works (I can put data in it and read it out in an other form). Now, I want to get the column price and put it in a graph. I can draw the graph already with hard coded values. I'm trying:

```
Cursor item0 = _dbHelper.fetcAllBoughtItems();
startManagingCursor(item0);
String xaxis[]=new String[4];
        xaxis[0]= item0.getString(item0.getColumnIndexOrThrow(databaseManager.KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM));
        xaxis[1]="2007";
        xaxis[2]="2008";
        xaxis[3]="2009";
```

I get the follow error (I know it's telling me what's wrong, but I can't get it fixed)

```
04-27 10:03:21.382: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Adforce.files/Adforce.files.summarySpendBudget}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 5
```

Can someone help me please?
Regards

**Edit:**
fetchAllBoughtItems() code is:
`public Cursor fetchAllBoughtItems(){ //function to fetch all bought items
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_ItemB, new String[]{KEY_ROWID_ItemB, KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM, KEY_PRICE_ItemB }, null, null, null, null, null); 
    }`

Comment: databaseManager.KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM = -1 ?

Comment: It is a string (I check before entering into database), so it can't be -1, if that is what you mean

Comment: It is column name. Are you sure your db table has such column?

Comment: public static final String KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM = "boughtItem";
this is the table, I create database with: private static final String DATABASE_ItemB_CREATE = "create table itemsBought (_id integer primary key autoincrement,boughtItem text not null, priceItem text not null, clothestype integer not null, photoId text, date text not null);"; and then:
db.execSQL(DATABASE_ItemB_CREATE); //create second database

Comment: maybe you did a typo in "autoincrement,boughtItem text not null"
try using "autoincrement," + KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM + " text not null" ... so even if u made a typo in KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM it will appear in create statment in the same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetcAllBoughtItems() returns Cursor without column named databaseManager.KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM

fix fetcAllBoughtItems()

**EDIT:**

add `item0.moveToFirst()` before `item0.getString(...` and check if will return true

Comment: the thing is, I use fetcAllBoughtItems somewhere else, and then the cursor returns the right thing, this is the same function.

Comment: provide code of fetcAllBoughtItems Cursor DOESN'T have column named databaseManager.KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM and that's why  getColumnIndexOrThrow(databaseManager.KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM) throws error

Comment: I don't get it, then why can I get the KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM elsewhere? In an other class I do: notesCursor = _dbHelper.fetchAllBoughtItems();startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
String[] from = new String[]{databaseManager.KEY_BOUGHT_ITEM,databaseManager.KEY_PRICE_ItemB};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text3};
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.boughtitems_row, notesCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(notes);
This works great, and I get all my data from that database

Comment: for  Flying Spaghetti Monster's sake just show us fetcAllBoughtItems code (once time method is fetchAllBoughtItems seconf is fetcAllBoughtItems without 'h') ... so prolly u made a typo

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post. I changed fetcAllBoughtItems to fetchAllBoughtItems, I saw the typo while reading your reaction. So there I don't think that there is a typo, function is fetchAllBoughtItems and I call it that way